# Using a CA cert for pulling builder image for S2I build

Tags: openshift

I have a `BuildConfig` that has the following `strategy` block:

```
    strategy:
      sourceStrategy:
        from:
          kind: DockerImage
          name: <insecure registry pullspec>
        forcePull: true
        incremental: true
      type: Source
```

The builder image is coming from a registry that uses a self-signed certificate. How do I tell the build config to either A) use a CA certificate for the registry or B) ignore the certificate errors?

I have tried adding the CA certificate as an opaque secret, and then using `pullSecret`, but that didn't work:

```
  strategy:
    sourceStrategy:
      forcePull: true
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: <insecure registry pullspec>
      incremental: true
      pullSecret:
        name: <name of opaque secret with ca cert>
    type: Source
```

I am running this build in an OpenShift 3.11 cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually described in the documentation how to add your own root CA as an `additionalTrustedCA`:
[Setting up additional trusted certificate authorities for builds](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/builds/setting-up-trusted-ca.html)

Here are the relevant parts:

> Create a ConfigMap in the openshift-config namespace containing the trusted certificates for the registries that use self-signed certificates. For each CA file, ensure the key in the ConfigMap is the registry’s hostname in the hostname[..port] format:
>
> ```
> $ oc create configmap registry-cas -n openshift-config \
>    --from-file=myregistry.corp.com..5000=/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.corp.com:5000/ca.crt \
>    --from-file=otherregistry.com=/etc/docker/certs.d/otherregistry.com/ca.crt
> ```
>
> Update the cluster image configuration:
>
> ```
> $ oc patch image.config.openshift.io/cluster --patch '{"spec":{"additionalTrustedCA":{"name":"registry-cas"}}}' --type=merge
> ```

Comment: I assume the `oc patch` command must also be run in the `openshift-config` project, right?

Comment: Also, looks like `openshift-config` is not a valid namespace: `Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "openshift-config" not found`. And this is after logging in as `system:admin`.